# Is there an equivalent Windows command for the w command in Linux/Unix?

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface

Is there an equivalent in Windows for the `w` command in Linux/Unix?

Comment: What does the w command do in linux/unix?

Comment: @matthew: like ` who`, it shows the users connected to the system.

Comment: Who and W are different....

Comment: @campo: indeed, but they both show connected users. `w` is more detailed as it shows what the users are doing.

Comment: In Windows:
No exact command match.


Tasklist.exe gives a complete list of what programs each logged on entity has launched, and processor and memory utilization info for each, rather than the single app that W gives.  

Psloggedon.exe gives a session list, and how they are authenticated - console vs network, but has no process info.  WMI may be able to give information on both, but it is more complex.  You'll need to say something about why you have interest,

Answer (score 4):

depending on what you are looking for `query user`, `query session`, or `query process` will provide similar functionality.  Tasklist /v is also useful.  Typical windows workstations are single purpose.  Servers usually have few actual users on them (with the exception of terminal servers) so I haven't seen a real need for a "w" type command.

Yet another way would be to use `WMIC list process brief` However to get owner info you would have to call getowner for a process you are interested in.

for detailed process info you can use

```
wmic /output:wmic.html process list full /format:hform
```

and view the wmic.html file in your browser

Answer (score 3):

I would use

```
tasklist
```

there are various switches at

```
tasklist /?
```

that should accomplish what you requested